# How can I make HIGH LOW loop with analog value

Tags: arduino

So I am putting lights in my room and they will be esp32 controlled
esp32 has capacitive touch so it will be controlled using that
My problem is that I need  to control it with one touch to turn on and second to turn off
I have tried some things but they didn't work out so this is code

```
const int touchPin = 4; 
const int ledPin = LED_BUILTIN;

const int threshold = 10;
int touchValue;

boolean oldSwitchState = LOW;
boolean newSwitchState = LOW;
int i;
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
  touchValue = touchRead(touchPin);
  i = touchRead(touchPin);
  Serial.println(touchValue);
  boolean s;
  s = map(i,20,50,1,0);
  Serial.println(s);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, 1);
  newSwitchState = s;
  if ( newSwitchState != oldSwitchState ){
       if ( newSwitchState == HIGH ) { 
        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);  
 }
       else{ 
        digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
 }

       oldSwitchState = newSwitchState;
    }
  delay(500);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is code that worked

```
const int touchPin = 4; 
const int ledPin = LED_BUILTIN;

int touchValue;
bool outputstate = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  touchValue = touchRead(touchPin);
  i = touchRead(touchPin);
  Serial.println(touchValue);
  if(touchValue < 30){
    outputstate = !outputstate;
    digitalWrite(ledPin, outputstate);
    delay(1000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you want you need to modify your if... else part where you are comparing newSwitchState && oldSwitchState.

Instead of checking whether newSwitchState is HIGH or LOW, you can maintain another variable which **toggles** on state change.

Something on these lines.

```
...

boolean toggleState = false;

...

void loop() {
    ...

    if ( newSwitchState != oldSwitchState ) {
        if ( toggleState == false ) {
            toggleState = true;
            digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);  
        }
        else {
            toggleState = false;
            digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
        }
        oldSwitchState = newSwitchState;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```cpp
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WebServer.h>

const char index_html1[] PROGMEM = {"<!DOCTYPE html> \n<html> \n<head>\n<style>\n.button {\n background-color: #4CAF50;\n border: 2px solid #4CAF50;;\n color: white;\n padding: 15px 32px;\n text-align: center;\n text-decoration: none;\n display: inline-block;\n font-size: 16px;\n margin: 4px 2px;\n cursor: pointer;\n}\n</style>\n</head>\n<body> \n<center><h1 style=\"color:blue;\">ESP32 Web server LED controlling example</h1></center> \n<center><h2 style=\"color:black;\">Web Server Example Microcontrollerslab.com</h2></center> \n<center><h2 style=\"color:Green;\">Press \"ON\" button to turn on led and \"OFF\" button to turn off LED</h3></center>\n<center>\n<a href=\"/26/on\"><button class=\"button\">ON</button></a>\n\n<img src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAAC0CAYAAABi3Il7AAASXElEQVR4Xu1da7qjIAy1a3LW5F1TXVNdk/OFEAgBFBCQPvrnzrRWLYeTk4QQH9PvNdQIPIa6m4Ob2ffXjh9v0zSt+u/R3c/TNC36gHl6PP69xW8d9iYRABj8v8pzBkACgP6G/O1D3VQ7EDimwBwAml4A0DIMg4YAZN9nzYbKZMg+HYD1vBWcWwDxmSBnbfZIVvoC3Qfqzx1mrSsgCARoAjcZlcay6mn4BAHG9NObboDs+1ODUXXkOp2snylrDgiy4l+ngWt9GTBja9Mxa3ryfV92jBk+6dVWX5oBgmCAVoyuF+WT5fGYqo9f9RN+lok6A6u+tlQF5DNN1Bko01STKVUAeR939nxwy44ApkA65rrgVwJk2uGGPlkv0oC6HrNcAuS9Y4u0IXZzXuSgHDkq11zjYkC+S7wRFtCKtElYDkoRIN8IBppkAGVTY3YOTBkohYCMkp3NNTtXj5egQBaCFstCZixfU7IB2XcQ8G9+uaDQSMQD4VdWOj8LkG+NM8LTzzdJ4XUdcIfRzKW8kg88t5kpl/u0Y3yTFJ606aAkAfKdIp46eXyTFGZKmsgnAvKtIn4GCgbDMnUSn8DnenIKyE83zkCBz0MsgQU5Xq4Udgbk2Q8B+ZmqFDDgmLB7i6YLXtYlPktEngDyiQtMqYOcd1xsoP0w4VhLooCgV5VSIZh34597dIwloSXseMB4AMi3B4D5UyfOEt/SxI4NAvLTjnww8BthLyo8nmGWRAD5aUcZJHFTFE45+QBGAPmZq/qA+B4XrjK6aRUPkF+KpAwK+lZcR8KFgvL4ACA/dpRDEs5ZHReTu2brB0j56Ee+aQfYpuTd4NB+0S+6cwD5eVc10MH9JulF5S6rBCA/76oGJLnn4DoiAPlldXMHs87xliUCkJ+g1xng/LMQSwwg42wry/8xn/ENdAZ0Scsn7eF4V3h+gAyGHKZdPoAhfKMmLAS9a40xCntiFd5gk0kNOi2Jro/Xvu/zNk3bDO/KwrX32TAEwv5mgORXAsJUeo+6AIcho8cfZUBIXo+eOGUMGTn+OC+dyTGoY+99fOKmxXHrdeuCQcCNy5RlVEDabj0eV1dmAmQ8DTmrX+Jm6vWiXlr47r9/572xxmTJsAwJ72x9vfZg1yDg04OBkALQmGVOb8AQGNx5nqZtm6d5hjra89kvRR7OAawxQM2zjldqN0fLcS9Cxw7JEAz4tg07v6WYn9xhQGC2aZ5HKwQ0DBnH7d22p4nCW4ChBP2175tu+wGsG6cfi2HIOKKOgExs9tZrXyGXqLftNU3z3zQP049lSJMF5uo5zTPZd54sLItLwh7VrK8zUusoExiOwxBMGhIIscQg6gslGMMactROFsDAFrIW+Fwlqn088PRFcchY3d7AlMxz25nrsrD24JaeTzNEpa9V17dRUtWLdnNbuaUpLCwd1CvfG5Qh6Pa2ZUnr85fAwrK9o62pk42HWKF2Vzo891juLsI3MCBKbpt5QSOyA/sEr2OvqePA1e3zSxmA8aJ0VuSA6eiRXN9WDCHW1QW5RC/873iAjJM+sTdb39sa01zZ7DarXBwrFkFQauvIuAwJlJKO5mkhJDijISt7vSEzBoMjJRPJFkSLrUfTEUAEKq2e01Ihch/TXLnL1W+xP6RGmmODTTQq/hhR0G3S9E12UEEi8FqAqNgBj8pQJmukl9tqI7DHcDSzBUKMy7dXcm01WNYGxtNNn5/obUFqm9bR2wxr6VlPt0VjkDheTLJur2kpsv/EMOWzXWJZ6aCHvxfunxXp5DBaJyA+qPnub4sUTA1wQrVnb9V8xmZpc4S5dnBZAwoMekPdSg/aM40n7rhkm8OQOg5BLQjseeKlsgeAjBe5l+nIdZe5PiDxZ468UYu/ksIEWoxqtRRcClW8zV9CV9KxPK4cgbY1XiMBUthzkbAfbTtYOEEoN37yxORYqZKzqv5ThowYl1CSkJed0v5bXmeF4LUtJ0o3WhX69o7HEirExnJTTM9DsRtuwVW7cDUyFqBxAElpyp/EEGTJCG4wxhQboACpEBp9Nk2hiBqSJBopVpmYE7ukz/v0Iyv2fkdA7nWDyTwhIygNAgNP+9PdlgEKNLUPBI+9t2Q0DQy402SG3MsSWFtfJjP74V8qAwxDrRnBWWJAQ5u2zXNhHix9/sePTH9URQEg97AEhnxan5YCOO21iID1IsVw3lSpRCLTvNzlbeXtsc9iiGUJmYwaMyjlHFo7NBsUK5SIIzvIjIGZmmf6P9kyDcu86m1sKderd8yZmyuvlA3IPaZrnrYYQ7RGhLYmmFY02zQtNzAkF4xsk0Vo9g8W52mFmMIaIeVpWTZY99euLmq7RuJetJZSypS0mCN09iKGIEv6plQgGLQelpYPDQouPFlhIbCYL3ZDgFi22+sCIH0FXu0HPBp4HSACQ9DNlQzpGSDmCTlnSjEgyJJ+bWWPGGKidYo6DHOsI1a2/FtisvLc3CqibrWkX0EEMoR5u86go8kiYPAvpVmQLf1yWuXsKBZ1PjC9WGJjEasXUtiVZqgMCTNZZmNnj9TJNXZUAaSnGwwrhk5MGGCJit0ZQ+D+3oUdbwdI3GyxVIpgCICzLH0EvSTuqKohrulq7Qaz4FCZJmuWZMKRf9aPIekJxCNX4ZKX5QLSXuDRZPkaQu5wSNR7AVKDHdVMlvW62rIkZrKiAWO3TO91MacxrMYQFPe2FY/bCs1iQq6vbaDsBYYdRL0WO6ozpG2wSPksHewFNKS/ySrPWcV0pCpDEJB2KZUjL4uoI+OQ1l5WTXY0YQiC0kZL1hWqSCJJRCp2UBF7r8CwjmfF2VKdIe0AwUWqUPqE57LCkXqrOKQso9vF7XVd4DZmi5sslwU8/e5G6nAcLk7Vf9U2V81MViuWrCtskQ55Wabqp2su680Aqe0CU7E1ZXGxQI6qT+xaSatcFs0ESlLWN1eNGVI/cr83lwX6ZftAplQhlhjJJqLeJnKfJ/Sy/DiEGTG9LiK9rKuiTj0eqc/vtTWP7qJuAalbfhpPnbjlP/XT71CoBwxB5+GffphaCQPOvtOYIXXNFlaehOMQ80OhHMssUGFd4/XlW6iaXLBX6pbW7P9s4LtF6m3cX9xnPq1LNJdF5T/qOBEYwr5EbGBT+nqqthwo51uT9ud0Z00ZUtP9PVpTd7K9kOFVCUXujV1ZNcRMruoXr7Y7zBM9/7EU3ts0BAGpoSN2G0I4daKLHKgFc2Bpt7zpDAMk8dkkV4DqwJA68YhkiDIeonqRKt19k3WFIdajosdeXBnws+92AKRGGuWMIWjbbcbXX94tZwgGgPTskVZPbOioITUAwc5y/OWuqR+5vbTbqiQWIXOFT/ZpDUbTSN3GIjUA8TO93GS5QCFbbCkpEqesFMguzdKTfkqe8HNmpvjnzU1WLU8LS0ndCDzEElmX5e7OzS2Ww/UOWHTDtH7boLALQ2oCImeaFXVXM9zKxSsmCwWdHkb2ESarDiDWZMndUi5IVOMbEvV8DaH0ei9z1ZEh12OR4+0IvHIRzRKPV/D/+XsMOSA9zFVHQK7ntOR2BFthgrtxYx4YvZ8v6miu1APEVGOCtjmsbm4vmqyrgJDJOtgpZYJElyGkM3kMsf2sXlBFA1uwp815eGWO55RzbCcv67rrm7I/hH649MbQZOVpiKMfqp/zPP174NMkWr6aX4Bu/lppEEXq1MUBz+pv/KQAkYs6bdjJ0RAef+w77INvnVTsarLQbJUIu13H9kWdhNw3Y2FRB4bIjgOxuW7rrfbXa4cr9HB5u4k6AnK2H1H2vHJdXYotYmIeMlN2nzoFhNSwhryuGEAWEBWDzNv0r+AZvCWmraPJijEEgaDe7GSKvB8D6Q9nhqsjWdWJa8b4HmrsHuS/rGsMC1h0DNzLbvRCxSDiadQlA536nY6ASIbQAhJ2Dk15KUCc0h8Bgj4JZwY2F0hLmRBA3DzhwlQfQe9sslyG4FIr9b5KgUO5SqbdEk+1828raEVgkgoIfPXv78+ZpF/AEABimda0SRtBivQmEcjEw4AhHjs0wD1c3q4MgaeJYpUA2GiMfEd6xcDo5V3RWHTTEOVpaRcyx4S0Bi2kG3BNMFXkufUEpSsgyBLwjMagh2QFB//5fO4xsFpOkq6A8JnX8kednfsICGIGSgd6fx/LEGO24IeuWkvORq/S50cghCbKHWB0FXU+rlR0prS9sflKAUK5Gvo+OBA9yn7kfOtusoglj39YWgPmgEps+MCkEuNswL2JoN+QE4GAUA41xDsqRwNPMfjXdYy6XozAwGeAQEmmu17NgckBR64OSjBDLLTfwfwWZAugqh0cD9UtYl1VgAn3mDo5ahzX9WJ0w/sTonZVm4NvYQNes+bAgZEMCv1oWewQKn6IDZa6ND0FDlhhTCgwZPkmQBQSOgPCc1n4nqwWVDNXgeYGlQSYAU6bGzI78BcGWX2+7ztE3LAsSwXTEBshWKsOVrlLPk+Pv7XrpO16MTRZsJyrDJLzB9li0+TBGa0G160+Jx2CgQVd8v6qJVh2PefEBO5BXNSZJTcBovOxZh+Byc/qRu56oDBTiEDxRx+YOl53cSpuw/n1CPfE4HR+dllLp3vvD8gT0vC0eMcWpTxwjDuktUaAaAu07EIgx8cZ78jgz7R3EACnDT2MqUrUv8FkqR+v9UMNomCBGdgYYAQWEUg/OEQJ8lEmWGoWHBvSDn3+zuyAq3ZnCOrIonJaTnd9oyG0zVY32Q+ZKgOYOAdpk9QMdW5yHAh8OEgyx67hI4u/xcsCYdeBl/Z7mcjTY3KYfqjFLAmQ/pzOY8Y2ZJ7kej1XG+Z6Y+qAffhVXhY3O+ypLLG1EmdMEwX5KPgwQsYdCt8be/xtXa1I14sZtzeJHbQpqnQxS6zTc4+NM449Hgm9OdcMfkccQqLuWA4u4GTyBXP4BParhni7k8DTK6T7zL048Lb0ybnJWqC+99NzWRCorbF2SZROce24DSLJSyJkZLXKSVzCmamcBTYjFBCuKextrm70siBaF0GD81/uEgdYovAgV5c7a8SCkPerL2A8LoprqH+JdhJ0qkXd3zd4WZg70rbas+v0NC+aqSymkDNaAkpa4Aj5iceln3/oV5iy73UG5R5Rp8H0XFmpIyHvKxqOx3wq/32dXbb5M+5WCxA/HhCTeqdxCkTjxtaLqNs4QCGNcVMe8XQXD/6EiTMs0+fvDMYtGmKjdAr8WOrEpD0oWtcmzIvMuajLaD0UvfO+ApS41E8DJeSWBV1ek9P6pkidJxiNm8ki5hBDHBGXLqx91Cp7hp7v+vJzKNGmlArltO6N0m9hCAaHIOw6wWj8fz3rPS+IC71gzmlanmkQd2tVlpcYKljhxEZ9U+83AkJuLzclMUHnqQ32OGgpEl5Oy0+DuOrOruelukhDvin9DrPUieP4IhSbvV5qQzpNkSAy6nMJ8Xe7+7vB4XeIOiyp6kg95H6qiU1iLs1VIK6QXrATfYtdbAYkcZBzDh6DfJPJ4t4Mn6UyWOQ6QcGhzJBILywEkuN86UHn8ecEusL05AZ23KYhKOywJsL6IJqUBctnRdfR9VR3gGGelpOT4rEMj/zZMrIqbXVTKL2zvETe7pE6XVg91sIMAqvRMtUoTMClCTPr71q4JXDGvWX5Lsd7olwYASsaZN6Q5b0dEAMMLeeSu0vpFCdI5J6WaawYle3zDyRrmEd2Ixi3miwLiI5JYubHE3j6JisV8rT+IHo3jgT35MiR6L+GLifPbSZL3siuoncYSOrNGxlUE2/QegY/js4a0o3IipYCE89xl27wsRgHENIUkxIPpEO8jKEsoGPLvuS5yXovzjgu/jebqmE0xGMKpFUgTomlUEIxihF1ZoaMCaQkIr+SsHE3ubghrRuGIfzmlAcGLrEa1JTFc1YIEUqDGJdaDgF6d723HBw5HUMCQjesNl5i13e3Sp6bIcfltXqA55ARIoo3vAun+Fv7lvice383VS6m3BgcA5Xtf3//zNOfF5Utx24OSJzAurosJdWMwUYF27SqXcDT9Hw+va4NqffV8rihGQI/fFme+8qqVHDnkx5lY57IAdDZj1ixnR5J3f9kyN8+5E3JGbgsy76qqN5uVRaLu06ZydFGUgDj+Xw1fSjLFQa9BSB6U44FxKCB/5A6fgTIqKZqWLc3NrskS1RbStreJkxXDJBlWaZ17bvfI5ctb8EQ+lHzPJv+I+Y9hyPat3Iq2J0hGf73Dn+DfDjBDSYtCUQUJu4OMWR0U/V2JksCo7Y+4/4nrSHwf+wex/svgpnKaS6Qa2JqH/8f8TsYLbP4YsEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=' alt=''>\n <a href=\"/26/off\"><button class=\"button button2\">OFF</button></a>\n</center> \n</body> \n</html>"};
const char index_html2[] PROGMEM = {"<!DOCTYPE html> \n<html> \n<head>\n<style>\n.button {\n background-color: #4CAF50;\n border: 2px solid #4CAF50;;\n color: white;\n padding: 15px 32px;\n text-align: center;\n text-decoration: none;\n display: inline-block;\n font-size: 16px;\n margin: 4px 2px;\n cursor: pointer;\n}\n</style>\n</head>\n<body> \n<center><h1 style=\"color:blue;\">ESP32 Web server LED controlling example</h1></center> \n<center><h2 style=\"color:black;\">Web Server Example Microcontrollerslab.com</h2></center> \n<center><h2 style=\"color:Green;\">Press \"ON\" button to turn on led and \"OFF\" button to turn off LED</h3></center> \n<center>\n<a href=\"/26/on\"><button class=\"button\">ON</button></a>\n\n<img src='data:image/png;base64,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' alt=''>\n <a href=\"/26/off\"><button class=\"button button2\">OFF</button></a>\n</center>\n</body> \n</html>"};

const char *ssid = "******";
const char *password = "***********";

WebServer server(80);

void handleRoot()
{
    server.send_P(200, "text/html", index_html2);
}

void handleBulbOn()
{
    server.send_P(200, "text/html", index_html1);
    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
}

void handleBulbOff()
{
    server.send_P(200, "text/html", index_html2);
    digitalWrite(2, LOW);
}

void handleNotFound()
{
    String message = "File Not Found\n\n";
    server.send(404, "text/plain", message);
}

void setup(void)
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    Serial.println("");

    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
    }
    Serial.print("IP address:");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

    server.on("/", handleRoot);
    server.on("/26/off", handleBulbOff);
    server.on("/26/on", handleBulbOn);
    server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);
    server.begin();
    Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}

void loop(void)
{
    server.handleClient();
}
```

Comment: Guess you can add description explaining what the code is doing? for better understanding